# Maxima ezunits: apply a unit to all elements of a list

Tags: list, units-of-measurement, maxima

Since I discovered the `ezunits` package I make extensive use of it in Maxima, but I could not find a satisfactory way to apply a unit to the elements of a list.

For example `` [1,2,3]`hour `` apparently works

```
a: [1,2,3]`hour;
>> [1,2,3] ` hour

(5`km)/a[2];
>> 5/2 ` km/hour
```

but I cannot loop through it

```
makelist((5`km)/x, x, [1,2,3]`hour);
>>> makelist: third argument must be a number or a list; found: [1.0,2.0,3.0] ` hour
```

whereas, if I apply manually the unit to each element of list, everything works:

```
makelist((5`km)/x, x, [1`hour,2`hour,3`hour]);
[5 ` km/hour,5/2 ` km/hour,5/3 ` km/hour]
```

Thanks in advance for any help you will be able to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tellsimp` as suggested above is a good idea. Here is another which depends on the only-partially-documented `distribute_over` property:

```
(%i7) :lisp (setf (get '$\` 'distribute_over) '(mlist $matrix mequal))
(MLIST $MATRIX MEQUAL)
(%i7) [1,2,3]`m;
(%o7)                        [1 ` m, 2 ` m, 3 ` m]
```

Be very careful with the punctuation! Distinguish the backtick from the single quote carefully.

Note that I've made backtick distribute over lists, matrices, and equations, i.e.

```
(a = b)`m
```

simplifies to:

```
a`m = b`m
```

When I wrote the `ezunits` package, I thought about making backtick distribute over lists automatically, but decided against it. Do you have any comments on this topic? I'm interested to hear what users have to say about it.

Comment: In my modest experience I always needed the backtick to distribute units over lists.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think my motivation was to ensure that it's clear that all the elements in a list have the same units. In a list of the form [a tick b, c tick d, e tick f] whether the units are all the same or not can be determined only by examining every element. I think I was hoping to make it easier to handle lists of dimensional quantities, as from a data file or something. Maybe it is enough if (list backtick units)[k] evaluates or simplifies to (list[k] backtick units. EDIT: It turns out that is already implemented! Sorry for the noise, I guess it was a while ago.

Comment: Yes, ``(somelist`unit)[k]`` already evaluates to ``somelist[k]`unit``, but backtick does not distributes units over list elements (at least *not enough* to make the example in the question work). My question arises from such somewhat misleading behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be in the following function:

```
unit2list(l,u):= makelist(x`u,x,l)$
```

Not very elegant but seems to work.

Comment: You can define a simplification rule `matchdeclare(L, listp)$  matchdeclare(U, all)$  tellsimp(L\`U, unit2list(L, U))$` to make `makelist` example from the question work.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for the question as it was posed. When the global flag `listarith` is `true` (which is the default value), a lot of arithmetic operations distribute over lists. So in your example:

```
(%i22) a: [1,2,3]`hour;
(%o22)                         [1, 2, 3] ` hour
(%i23) (5`km)/a;
                                   5  5     km
(%o23)                         [5, -, -] ` ----
                                   2  3    hour
(%i24) %[2];
                                   5    km
(%o24)                             - ` ----
                                   2   hour
```